# Python only executes one if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am extremely new at python and programming in general so pardon if the answer is obvious.
I am trying to write  a program that will tell you what day Easter falls on through a range of years. 
I am running into a problem with my if statements. If the year is one of the years specified in the first if statement, it will not execute the second if statement even if day > 31.

```
year = int(input('Input a year: '))
a = year % 19
b = year % 4
c = year % 7
d = (19 * a + 24) % 30
e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) % 7

day = 22 + d + e

month = 'March'

if year == 1954 or year == 1981 or year == 2049 or year == 2076:
           day = day + 7

if day > 31:
           day = day - 31
           month = 'April'

print('Easter is on', month, day)
```

Comment: There is probably an issue with your indentation. Make sure you're using all spaces and not tabs.

Comment: Python would throw an IndentationError if there is an indentation issue; I copied this and ran it with no changes, and the second if statement executes just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is executing the second if statement.

Did you consider how large `day` would be?

If, for example, `year == 2049`, then:

```
a = 16
b = 1
c = 5
d = 28
e = 6
```

This leads to the initial assignment to day `day = 22+d+e` to set `day = 56`. In the first if, it is then set to `63`

63-31 = 32, which is what you are getting? (along with 'april' as month, indicating that it was reaching the if statement the whole time)

So perhaps you've misunderstood the algorithm used for determining the Easter date and not implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in your logic I believe. I modified the code a bit and found that the second IF is working

```
year = int(input('Input a year: '))
a = year % 19
b = year % 4
c = year % 7
d = (19 * a + 24) % 30
e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) % 7

day = 22 + d + e

month = 'March'

if year == 1954 or year == 1981 or year == 2049 or year == 2076:
  day = day + 7
if day > 31:
  print("day ", day)
  day = day - 31
  month = 'April'

print('Easter is on', month, day)
```

Gives the output :

```
Input a year: 1954
day  63
Easter is on April 32
```

If you see the result, `print("day ", day)` command is getting executed. Please revisit your logic. I think you should use the modulus instead of subtraction.